# Deployed functions but they are not showing up in Azure Portal

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

I'm having real trouble getting some basic Typescript functions deployed to Azure. I deployed using VS code, and the deployment was successful according to the Output window, but when I look at the Function App in the Azure Portal, there are no functions listed:

[image]

Also no functions appear in the Azure tab in VS code:

[image]

I checked my project structure and it mirrors what is suggested in the Typescript [developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=typescript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4#folder-structure):

```
<project_root>/
 | - .vscode/
 | - dist/
 | | - src/
 | | | - functions/
 | | | | - myFirstFunction.js
 | | | | - myFirstFunction.js.map
 | | | | - mySecondFunction.js
 | | | | - mySecondFunction.js.map
 | - node_modules/
 | - src/
 | | - functions/
 | | | - myFirstFunction.ts
 | | | - mySecondFunction.ts
 | - .funcignore
 | - host.json
 | - local.settings.json
 | - package.json
 | - tsconfig.json
```

I checked that `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags` is set to `EnableWorkerIndexing`, as someone suggested that in a different SO post. The Typescript files are being successfully compiled during deployment and appear in dist > src > functions.

I also tried deploying using the Core Tools. Again, the deployment was successful. It said that the zip package was uploaded, but no functions appear.

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you check account / tenant / subscription you are deploying ?

Comment: @Thomas Can you give me more details on what to check? I have limited permissions in this Azure account. Maybe that is the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a build error resulting from a missing npm dependency that prevented the functions from showing in the Azure Portal. There was no mention of the error upon deployment from VS Code (or Core Tools), so I guess the lesson here is to always run an `npm build` locally, prior to deployment, to ensure that everything is building correctly.

I thought for sure that an `npm build` was part of the deployment process and that errors would halt the deployment and be reported back, but that appears to be not the case.

Comment: @SPT - you absolutely don’t need to spam every answer you see with this repeated message. Not only that: the OP literally answered their own question - you’re harassing the OP to accept their own answer. *Please stop spamming answers with “accept” comments.*

Comment: @SPT - all of your “accept” comments have now been removed (aside from the one on this question - to ensure you see this) - please stop posting these.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to hate this answer as much as I do, and YMMV depending on your level of access, project phase, etc. I had exactly the same environment; Functions Model v4, Typescript Functions on node runtime, etc etc and I got exactly the same symptoms. In the end I lost my patience (after seeing this post with no positive answers, actually) and just deleted the Functions App to start again (hence YMMV).

The steps I took differently is that I *didn't* deploy from VS Code the second time. Instead, I created an example HTTP Trigger Function locally following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-typescript?pivots=nodejs-model-v4), tested and confirmed it worked locally, then basically stopped at Step 5 of [Run the function locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-typescript?pivots=nodejs-model-v4#run-the-function-locally). From that point, I published the local repo to a private GitHub repo, then created the Function App in the Azure portal, enabling GitHub Actions on the Deployment tab and pointing it to my new private repo (again, you might need to tweak this part depending on your resources). Once the new Function App was created I couldn't see anything, same as before, *until* I pushed a minor for-the-sake-of-it commit, which triggered the CI/CD pipeline and updated the whole Function App. Now I can see the HttpExample Function on the Overview page of the portal, as expected.

I think there must be something that gets mangled in the process of changing deployment sources, because ignoring the part where you deploy from VS Code and just going straight to manually creating a Function App with GitHub Actions for deployment worked a charm. Again, I really hope you can make use of this admittedly vague experiment and result, and I really hope you get it working because it's ruined my weekend, so I imagine you're feeling similar woe!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the insight! After reviewing my code with a co-worker, it turned out that there was a straightforward build error (missing npm dependency) resulting from a function that I had attempted to disable by commenting out the `app.timer` section. Unfortunately, both VS and the command line Core Tools showed the deployment as a success with no mention of the build error, so I went down the same rabbit hole that you did. That's good to know that the GitHub Actions route helped you out though. Just in case I encounter another issue with deployments.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, too! I get that the v4 is still in 'Preview', but it feels poorly documented and with really noticeable compatibility bugs so far...quite frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **function.json** file for your functions.

Should look something like this.

```
 {
  "disabled": true,
  "scriptFile": "test.js",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 */5 * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Gagan Bajwa. Every function has an individual function. Json.
I created  HTTP trigger functions with two function in typescript runtime stack.

**Function1 host.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/src/HttpTrigger1/index.js"
}
```

**Function2 host.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/HttpTrigger2/index.js"
}
```

- `I have given the scriptFile path in the function. Json.`

**Below is the folder structure and the status of running my code:**

[image]

**deployment status:**

[image]

**Output:**
I am able to see the functions in the Azure portal where I was deployed.

[image]

Comment: I am using the v4 runtime. I thought that the function.json files were required for v3 but not v4?